# Why might dogs get sick less frequently than their owners?

Tags: pathology

An article I was reading cited this study result "*A comparison of 2473 pairs of dogs and their owners found that dogs were about 50 per cent less likely to have had two or more acute illnesses in the previous year than their human family members (p < 0.01, preliminary data)*." The article is here http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3189355/.

In the absence of any species specific reasons, we would not only expect rates of sickness to be similar, but in fact, owing to dogs' extremely poor hygiene standards relative to humans, we would expect them to be sick vastly more often.

I have read a number questions on the general subject of humans appearing to get sick more than animals, but most have ended with a presumption (but without any evidence cited) that animals do get sick as often but we just don't see it. This study is the first I've seen on the subject and seems to demonstrate that it is a real phenomenon after all.

The author's explanation seems entirely based on meat-eating, which seems plausible, but perhaps a bit narrow. I wonder if anyone could offer any alternative explanation?

Answer (score 1):

The article is hypothetical. It's written as a discourse trying to explain why pets are sick less than their owners, while the foundation of that hypothesis is not founded: see section 4 of your linked paper:

> A hypothesis put forth in this discourse is that humans get sick more often than animals and, correspondingly, typically engage in medical practices more frequently than animals. There is relatively little direct evidence that might firmly refute or confirm this hypothesis.

So your question why

> humans appear [to] get sick more than animals

is more a question of *if*, rather than *why*.

I think the major problem with this article is that there is not a strict definition of 'sick'. What we may experience as being 'sick' may not be recognizable to us when an animal is in a physiological comparable state.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but I wasn't really asking for an review of the article itself, more a comment on the study it cites. The article might have been hypothetical in nature, but the study actually took place and got the results it did. It's these results I was interested in. I presume the uncertainty about observed 'sickness' is why the study chose dogs. It seems unlikely that such beloved pets were actually acutely ill without their owners knowing, and if they were that just means the question becomes 'why do humans exhibit more visible symptoms than animals?', hardly much different.

Comment: If your  question is on cited studies - cite those. The linked article is quite poor in its scope. What I mean is that the assumption of the article is iffy. I don't buy it.

Comment: Do women get "sick" more frequently than men? I bet a study would find that men do have fewer acute illnesses than women. But do they really? We know that men tend to go to the doctor much less than women for a number of reasons, ranging from laziness to stoicism to expense. Similar reasons apply to dogs and their owners, therefore I also strongly question the premise of this article.

Comment: Also, the population dynamics of pet dogs would be quite different from their human owners.

Comment: I agree with the above three comments. Dogs get sick, and probably on the same order of magnitude as humans. More than one human disease (like narcolepsy) has been solved because of canine conditions, and with genetic studies, more are certain to come. "...such beloved pets were actually acutely ill without their owners knowing..." How would their owners know? My dogs are quite beloved, but they just can't complain about certain illnesses. They get over it with time, or it becomes vet-worthy.

Comment: I don't mean to offend, but I originally asked about a study mentioned in a perfectly legitimate scientific journal. I was hoping someone might either offer an explanation or perhaps some evidence to the contrary. I'm not sure I see the sense, on a science site, of people adding comments that they 'reckon' it's probably not true. If anyone has any scientific, evidence based opinion, it would be good to hear. If you think dogs do get sick as much as humans then perhaps some studies showing this would be a useful contribution.

Comment: I hadn't realised I had come up against such a wall of preconception. According to Occam's Razor, if a study seems to show that dogs get sick less than humans, then we should presume that they do and then look for evidence to the contrary, not presume they don't because we don't like the conclusion and proceed to make up reasons why the study might be wrong. This is exactly the sort of confirmation bias that holds scientific investigation back, people decide on a world view and only accept evidence which supports it, anything that doesn't gets picked apart until it can be safely swept away.

Comment: I'm not quite sure where the vitriol is coming from, I did not say that any study proved it conclusively, but was careful to use 'might' in my question and 'seems to show' in my comments, please don't put words in my mouth. If mentioning an analytical axiom by name constitutes a 'lecture', then I'm not sure there is any value to continued discussion. I asked the question 'Why might dogs get sick more than their owners?' An answer would be a scientific reason why they do or a study showing they don't, I did not ask for a personal opinion about the value of the article.

Comment: Your question finishes with: "*The author's explanation seems entirely based on meat-eating, which seems plausible, but perhaps a bit narrow. I wonder if anyone could offer any alternative explanation?* It implies you take the finding for granted. The question you now pose in your comment is different than the one in your question body.

Comment: I presume you have deleted your previous comments? It looks like I'm having a conversation with myself which is misleading to anyone reading this. With regards to your remaining comments, I did indeed take the finding for granted, for the time-being, it was published in a reputable journal and I had no evidence to the contrary (and still don't), it seemed entirely the rational thing to do. All I did in my comment is flip it on it's head, it's the same question either way, what scientific, evidence based, explanation could there be for the results of this study?